# catkin rosserial_arduino not generating custom package messages

Tags: arduino, catkin-make, rosserial, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've made good progress with building my Arduino projects with CMake, but have hit a snag. My project uses custom messages in a separate package, and using make_libraries.py separately, everything works as expected. Cleaning the workspace and running `catkin_make verbose=1 robot_arduino_firmware_sensors` where robot_arduino is my arduino package and firmware_sensors is my c++ path (firmware/sensors.cpp). I can see the make_libraries script running, with the Arduino messages generated, except at the bottom is `failed to generate libraries for the following packages: robot_msgs`. That of course means that compiling my Arduino firmware fails.

Most information seems to say I should source indigo's setup.bash, which works when using make_libraries.py separately but I can't seem to include that in the catkin script. Seeing as it works correctly when separate, I suspect that may be the only issue. Anyone have a suggestion?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204601/catkin-rosserial_arduino-not-generating-custom-package-messages/) by [Wes G](https://answers.ros.org/users/8681/wes-g/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2015-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answers and comments here pointed me in the correct direction, which turned out to be sourcing my workspace correctly. I cleared the /devel and /build folders, then ran `source <ws>/install/setup.bash` and `catkin_make`. No custom message errors were reported. I updated my firmware code, compiled and uploaded and now I'm in business.

---

Originally posted by [Wes G](https://answers.ros.org/users/8681/wes-g/) with karma: 33 on 2015-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0